# Mobile sending message to each other with rails backend

Tags: ios, ruby-on-rails, sockets

I did some search but non of them satisfy my requirements, may be I searched the wrong keywords, if so please point me to the right direction.

I have Android and iOS client app, and Rails for backend. Mobile users can login to their account and send message to their friends. Right now I'm using http request + Push Notification to implement this. More specific, we have client `A` and `B`, `A` will send a message along with `B`'s id, and server will push that message to `B` and add that message to a `messages` table with `unread` property. If `B` open message page, those messages of `A` and `B` will become `read`.

After I did some research, I realized if both `A` and `B` are messaging to each other, (i.e `A`'s message page is sending to `B`, and vice versa), it would be better to use socket to send messages, more efficient.

Now my question is I should use Rails as `server socket` and each client just connect to `server`, or one of `A` or `B` will be the server socket? If Rails as `server socket` and there are lots of traffic or open sockets at the same time, is that gonna be a problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you can use [faye](https://github.com/faye/faye),  simple pub/sub messaging for the web/android/ios.
faye:https://github.com/faye/faye

ios:https://github.com/jayztemplier/FayeClient

android:https://github.com/saulpower/Android-Faye-Client